# How to perform a VCA on demographic estimates in R

Tags: r, demography

I want to perform a variance component analysis on avian demographic estimates (annual adult survival, per capita recruitment, and population growth rate) in R. I have used the program RMark to attain these estimates, their SE's, and their ucl/lcls, and now want to perform the VCA. I have tried var.components within RMark, but the function seems to have issues producing negative outputs... For reference, survival should be bounded between 0-1, and rec./pop.growth bounded between 0-infinity. I want to find a package that can allow me to define the bounds (or proper distribution) of the data, while also incorporating my SE (standard error). Any recommendations?

Thanks!